# Saber valor que devuelve un formulario onsubmit en CanvasInput HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

Antes de nada saludos a todos y decir que soy muy novato, cualquier corrección es bienvenida, tanto de la pregunta que estoy haciendo como el uso de esta web...

Estaba intentando que el método `onsubmit()` de la librería `"CanvasInput"` de HTML me devolviera el valor que escribo en el formulario...

El valor que me devuelve es el siguiente:

```
function
```

Código Javascript:

```
var input = new CanvasInput({
  canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
  value: '',
  onsubmit: function() {alert(this.value);},
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente cuando llamas a `this` estas haciendo referencia a la función y no a la nueva instancia de CanvasInput, como la función onsubmit será llamada después de crear el objeto, puedes llamar simplemente a `input.value`.

Esto debería funcionar:

```
var input = new CanvasInput({
  canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
  value: '',
  onsubmit: function() {
    alert(input.value);
  },
});
```

Comment: Gracias! No te voy a mentir, hacía mucho que no entraba y ya no sé donde puedo probar el código. pero estoy muy agradecido por tu respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Según puedo ver en código fuente de CanvasInput ([Linea 880](https://github.com/goldfire/CanvasInput/blob/master/CanvasInput.js#L880)), el manejador del evento recibe un segundo parámetro que es efectivamente el CanvasInput.

Por lo que puedes agregar este parámetro a la función callback para obtener el valor.

```
var input = new CanvasInput({
  canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'),
  value: '',
  // aquí agregar y usar los parámetros 
  onsubmit: function(e, canvasInput) { alert(canvasInput.value); },
});
```

Comment: Gracias! No te voy a mentir, hacía mucho que no entraba y ya no sé donde puedo probar el código. pero estoy muy agradecido por tu respuesta

Comment: @AlbertoGarcíaOlmedo no hay problema, si puedes probarlo en algún momento, acepta alguna de las respuestas de modo que otros sepan que resolviste el problema.